# Method to force store operation on C variable

Tags: c, volatile

Is there a way to guarantee that the compiler writes the value of a variable to the stack location of that variable for a specific assignment operation?
In essence, I'm doing

```
int x = 0;
x = foo(x);
work1
work2
```

where x isn't used until work2, but work1 will scramble the register that holds x, so I want to guarantee that the assignment writes it to the stack.  I know I can use the volatile keyword (i.e. `volatile int x = 0`), however I don't need that level of optimization of all accesses to x, only this specific one.

The details of the register scrambling have to do with parallel execution and cannot be avoided.

Edit:
I'm compiling with clang 12.0.0 on an x86_64 system running linux.  I'm executing on the same system.

Edit2:
I mentioned in the comments, but it's a bit more nuanced than being clobbered.  Essentially one core may execute `x = foo(x)` and another core will longjump into the function and execute `work1`.  Once both have completed the work, one of them at random will continue with `work2`.  The reason it can't be stored in a register and must be written to memory is because although the two cores are operating on the same stack frame, they don't necessarily have the same registers after the second core longjumps into work1, and the store operation can happen after the longjump.  None of this can be changed, the only question is whether I can force x to operate as though it were volatile for a single operation and then act normally afterwards.

Comment: Simply don't mix C and inline assembler in the same function?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. `volatile` is generally used for memory-mapped hardware registers, it rarely makes sense otherwise. Why would you want to make sure the value is written if you know it is clobbered right after that?

Comment: If possible at all, it will be highly compiler-specific.  The general language standard does not get down to such a low level.  Please state the compiler you are using and other relevant details.

Comment: `Volatile` also helps in parallel programs where a value may unexpectedly change by forcing a read or write on every access.  In my program, if the value is written to a register, it may not be visible during work2.  It's a bit more nuanced than being clobbered, as the different sections can be executed on separate cores and out of order, with the only guarantee being that `x = foo(x)` happens before `work2` but I wanted to keep the problem definition simple.  The order and which core it executes on are determined at runtime, with both sections of code executing on the same stack frame.

Comment: I added the compiler and system, the exact distro of Linux may vary so I didn't specify, I'm executing on machines running both Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: There are a few possible stories:  `1:` your code looks like above, in which case you are fine.   Your compiler handles the details. `2:` your code has strange compiler extensions, like __attribute__ and __asm__, in which case you are no longer writing in C, you are writing in a language of your own design.  `3:` you have external assembly functions that think they can hide values in non-volatile registers.  They can't; they have to conform to the ABI for your implementation.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] for us.

Comment: Does `*(volatile int *)&x = foo(x);` work?

Comment: Did it *work* or *happen to work*?  The former has a certain resilience whereas the latter has a certain fragility.

Comment: @mevets I believe this does exactly what I need, since the compiler can't optimize out the store and will know to do a load for the first use of x but none after that.  Also for your comment about the possible stories, I'm working in #2 using setjmp/longjmp as well as some inlined asm and modification of the stored values in setjmp/longjmp to enable parallel execution.

Although I agree/understand this solution is somewhat fragile, it's for prototyping and a long term implementation will have compiler support so I can make sure it does exactly what I want.

Comment: It is very obscurely documented, but any local variables that need to survive a longjmp have to be declared volatile.   Its been that way since c89.

Comment: @mevets I was under the impression that only variables which were changed between setjmp and longjmp needed to be declared volatile, since setjmp saves all of the register values and then longjmp restores them to the state of the save, clobbering anything that's changed but preserving variables that didn't change.  You're right though that this solution is undefined behavior according to the standard, although I'm likely going to stick with it for now as the behavior with my system should be reliable.



This is really just a temporary measure until I get compiler support.